# Is it possible to solve the equation $x \times b + y \times c + z \times d = v$ for $b, c, d$?

Tags: vectors, cross-product

I have four fixed vectors $\vec x$ , $\vec y$ , $\vec z $ and $\vec v$

is it then possible to find $\vec b$, $\vec c$ and $\vec d$ with the equation:

$\vec x \times \vec b + \vec y \times \vec c + \vec z \times \vec d = \vec v$

x = [10, 0,  0]
y = [10, 0, 10]
z = [0,  0, 10]
v = [0,  0, 230]

(these are just values i picked randomly)

Comment: Is $m$ supposed to be a point?

Comment: mA is just the name of the point

Comment: So you have fixed vectors $x,y,z,v$, and you want to solve $x\times b+y\times c+z\times d=v$ for $b,c,d$, am I right?

Comment: yes, that would be what i'm trying to achieve

Comment: Welcome to math.se. I encourage you to post your attempts to solve it or some other context for your question. It was increase the chances that you'll get an answer, and also an answer suited to your needs.

Comment: Hint:  There is always a solution $(b,c,d)$ for any $v$ iff $x,y,z$ are linearly independent, in which case $x\times y$, $y\times z$, and $z\times x$ are linearly independent as well.  You can take a solution $b=\beta y$, $c=\gamma z$, and $d=\delta x$ for some scalar $\beta,\gamma,\delta$.  Show that $\beta=\frac{z\cdot v}{\Delta}$, $\gamma=\frac{x\cdot v}{\Delta}$, and $\delta=\frac{y\cdot v}{\Delta}$, where $\Delta=x\cdot(y\times z)=y\cdot(z\times x)=z\cdot(x\times y)$.  In your example, $\beta=2.3$, $\gamma=0$, and $\delta=2.3$.

Comment: But of course, there are other solutions.

Comment: I'll try to work this one out

Comment: when I try to calculate $\Delta$ it returns 0, and later it is used in a division. I see a problem there
when i do $y \times z$ it returns [0,-100,0] and if i later do $ x \cdot  [0,-100,0]$ it returns 0

Comment: Oh, I misread your vectors.  In my mind, $x=[10,0,10]$, $y=[0,10,0]$, $z=[0,0,10]$.  However if I use your correct vectors, then yes $\Delta=0$.  This means $x,y,z$ are not linearly independent.  Therefore, a solution might not exist.

Comment: Hmm, I made a mistake.  You need at least two linearly independent vectors from $x,y,z$.  WLOG $y$ is dependent of $x$ and $z$, but $x$ and $z$ are independent.  Then you can take $c=0$.  Now $x\times z$, $x\times (x\times z)$ and $z\times (x\times z)$ are linearly independent.  So you may take $b=\beta z+\gamma(x\times z)$ and $d=\delta (x\times z)$ if $$v=\beta(x\times z)+\gamma\big(x\times (x\times z)\big)+\delta\big(z\times (x\times z)\big).$$  Note that $\beta=\frac{(x\times z)\cdot v}{|x\times z|^2}$, $\gamma=-\frac{z\cdot v}{|x\times z|^2}$, and $\delta=\frac{x\cdot v}{|x\times z|^2}$.

Comment: In your example, $\beta=0$, $\gamma=-0.23$, and $\delta=0$.  That is, $b=[0,23,0]$, $c=0$, $d=0$.  However, if $x,y,z$ are parallel, you have no hope of solving the equation except when $v\perp x,y,z$, in which case you can just take $b=-\frac{x\times v}{|x|^2}$, $c=d=0$ if $x\ne 0$.

Comment: You say you have three fixed vectors, but I count four.

Comment: whoops, my bad, that was a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think of it in terms of components, you have three equations (one for each dimension) and nine unknowns (three components each for $b,c,d$.)  You are short six equations for a unique solution.  Finding some solution should be quite possible unless there are dependencies in your vectors.

Comment: Do you know any keywords, so I can find (if it exists) a solution easier.

Comment: I would just pick noncoplanar $b,c,d$ and form the cross products.  See if the cross product vectors are linearly independent.  If they are, you can find a solution that just multiplies each by a constant using the standard technique of expressing $v$ in the basis of the products.  If the products are dependent, they lie in a plane and you need to adjust one so the resultant is out of the plane.

Comment: is there a minimum amount that one point needs to be out of the plane

Comment: No.  As long as it is out of the plane the three vectors will span all space.  In a computer environment having the three vectors almost coplanar will make the computational errors much larger, but that is not a mathematical problem.